# How to use Lombok with JPA Metamodel in Spring Gradle project?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, gradle, lombok

In my project, JPA Metamodel is already been implemented. any_.java files are generated in "/build/generated" folder.
However, now I am implementing Lombok in my project and removing getter and setter properties. Now project can't detect all any_ classes.

How can I fix these issues? Are there any concurrency issue between Lombok and JPA criteria/Metamodel?

Note: I have added all required dependency for Gradle and annotation wherever needed.

Thank you.

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alKGm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer.. :)

It was needed to add

```
annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20"
```

in build.gradle file. Only "Enable annotation processing" checked in Intellij would not work.

Answer (score -1):

each class w/o getters and setters must be decorated with `@Data` annotation. If you need constructors: `@NoArgsConstructor`, `@AllArgsConstructor`. For more information please read the project lombok documentation. Also you can use `@ToString` and `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotations which tell to lombok to geenerate some parts of code

Answer (score -1):

Frist of all ,you need add a dependency

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Use @Data to add getters and setters to all variables in class.
Of course you can use @Getter annotations to generate getters for a single variable，the same is true of @Setter.And Lomok have a lot of annotations,you can see api in  website : https://projectlombok.org/

If you use Intelij IDEA , you can download a plugin 'lombok' ,it can help you use lomok better.